# Resharper Live Templates for editing WiX source files

Tags: wix, resharper, votive

I'm writing a few WiX files today and there's a lot of repetitve typing involved, so it looks to me like Resharper's Live Templates would be very useful here. Does anyone know of any?

I know it's not too hard to write new Live Templates so I may end up answering my own question in a couple of hours, but if anyone can point me to pre-exisitng ones that would be great.

As an aside any other WiX editing tips would be appreciated:-)

Comment: I'm guessing that you and Martin Peck work together on the same project given that you both just asked the same question with seconds of each other
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806825/resharper-templates-or-plug-ins-for-wix-wxs-file-editing

Comment: +1 cos I just asked the same question!

Comment: @Eoin: Correct. My question is now deleted.

Comment: @Eoin :-) not closely enough it would seem...

Comment: SO, bringing colleagues together ;-)

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the +1. Makes a change. ;-)

Comment: @steve hah!... TeamCommunicationException ;)

Comment: If you end up writing new Live Templates, would you consider contributing them to the WiX toolset community? Sharing shows caring. <wink/>

Comment: Sure. They're pretty simple, but I'm happy to share... do you have a URL?

Comment: zip'em and send them to me (http://robmensching.com/blog has contact information at very bottom on the right). I'll find a good place for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually only needed a couple of very simple ones...

For creating file components:

```
 <Component Id="C_$COMP_ID$" Guid="$GUID$">
        <File Id="F_$FILE_ID$" Name="$FILENAME$" />
 </Component>
```

I wired up $GUID$ to the "generate new guid" macro.

Then an even more simple one for creating directory entries:

```
<Directory Id="D_$DIR_NAME$" Name="$NAME$" />
```

The handy thing I found with the Live Templates was the ability to assign one of the fields to the clipboard value, so when adding a new file I could highlight the file's name and ctrl-C it to the clipboard and then run the template, but it only saves an tiny bit of typing.

I'll probably write a few more next time I'm editing WiX files, I'd be happy to share but they are so easy to write and customise to personal preference I'm not sure there's going to be a huge demand:-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Votive? because then you get InteliSense when working on wxs.
if you are not using Votive then you can put the [Wix XSD into Visual Studio XSD repository to get InteliSense](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/10/18/wix-hints-for-new-users-part-1-of-3.aspx).

Comment: Yep, am using Votive, but worth checking:-)